# Equals over String literal and String coming from NumberFormat fails due to different byte representation

Tags: java, java-9

I was playing around with Java 9 with the prod code. And I found a couple of Formatting tests failing. 
After some research, I was able to create a class to reproduce the issue. Which happens in Java 9 but not in Java 8.

The class is here
https://pastebin.com/87sA5WMb

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FormatFails {
    public static void main(String... args){

        Currency currency = Currency.getInstance("EUR");
        NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
        currencyFormatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
        currencyFormatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        currencyFormatter.setCurrency(currency);

        String expected = "123 457 €";
        String obtained = currencyFormatter.format(123456.789);
        System.out.println(expected);
        System.out.println(obtained);
        System.out.println(expected.equals(obtained));

        System.out.format("Bytes from expected: %s\n",Arrays.toString(expected.getBytes()));
        System.out.format("Bytes from obtained: %s\n",Arrays.toString(obtained.getBytes()));       
    }

}
```

Basically comparing 2 strings:

- An string literal and
- A formatted string in Locale.FRANCE produced using NumberFormat

Using equals on both fails, because of the following:

```
123 457 €
123 457 €
false
Bytes from expected: [49, 50, 51, -62, -96, 52, 53, 55, 32, -30, -126, -84]
Bytes from obtained: [49, 50, 51, -62, -96, 52, 53, 55, -62, -96, -30, -126, -84]
```

As you can see there are a different number of bytes and different representation. I don't know how to work around this and more important which is the change in Java9 that is affecting the code.

The result using plain old Java 8 is as follows:

```
123 457 €
123 457 €
true
Bytes from expected: [49, 50, 51, -62, -96, 52, 53, 55, 32, -30, -126, -84]
Bytes from obtained: [49, 50, 51, -62, -96, 52, 53, 55, 32, -30, -126, -84]
```

Java 9 version used

```
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
```

which is the latest version available.

Comment: Note that it's the space character that is different.

Comment: In particular the second space is changed from U+0020 space to U+00A0 nonbreaking space; the first space already is nonbreaking in both/all versions.

Comment: Is this a bug, something I don't know how to handle? Something else?

Comment: Interesting, there is a [bug entry for this](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4510618) in Oracle's bug tracker (thousand separator being a non-breaking space in French locale). Seems like an old issue that might have changed back and forth between Java versions.

Comment: Hmm.. actually the thousand separator already is a non-breaking space in Java 9 and 8 so this issue is slightly different. But the workarounds proposed in the issue could be possibly used here.

Comment: On Java8, using the [same code](https://github.com/namannigam/Jigsaw/blob/master/internal/src/experiment/FormatFails.java) as shared by you I would get `Bytes from expected: [49, 50, 51, 32, 52, 53, 55, 32, -30, -126, -84]
Bytes from obtained: [49, 50, 51, -62, -96, 52, 53, 55, 32, -30, -126, -84]` which then seems to be rectified in Java9 where I get `Bytes from expected: [49, 50, 51, 32, 52, 53, 55, 32, -30, -126, -84]
Bytes from expected: [49, 50, 51, -62, -96, 52, 53, 55, -62, -96, -30, -126, -84]`

Comment: Who said that locale-specific data is guaranteed to be constant? The French government could decide to declare a different standard format for monetary values, say, using `⚥` as grouping separator, tomorrow and you can be sure, there would be a follow-up Java update accommodating the change…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JDK 9 has moved to use CDLR locale data by default. Links to the JEP and more information on this can be found in the JDK 9 release notes (see http://jdk.java.net/9/release-notes#JDK-8008577). The release note and JEP document the system property can you can use to configure the JDK to use the legacy JRE locale data where needed.

Comment: So setting `-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,CLDR` should restore the behavior to that of Java 8?

Comment: It does 123 457 €
123 457 €
true
Bytes from expected: [49, 50, 51, -62, -96, 52, 53, 55, 32, -30, -126, -84]
Bytes from obtained: [49, 50, 51, -62, -96, 52, 53, 55, 32, -30, -126, -84]

Comment: However, I still feel weird about the issue. I mean, why would the blank space be encoded differently? I guess this explains the issue:               >"We cannot be responsible for the validity of the data coming from CLDR; >we assume that it is "good data".